# jQuery ,Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autoNumeric is not a function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement the autoNumeric jQuery plugin but I keep getting this error message in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autoNumeric is not a function

Markup:

```
 <input type="text" class="employee_annual_salary />   
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.co.uk/assets/js/autoNumeric.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $(".employee_annual_salary").autoNumeric('init');
     });
 </script>
```

I have these scripts in the header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.co.uk/assets/js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.co.uk/assets/js/autogrow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.co.uk/assets/js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: How does this solve my question.  I've looked in that question and it doesn't explain why i get that error?

Comment: is autoNumeric part of jquery and jquery UI?  I thought it was a third party plugin: https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric

Comment: according to the error info, you may need to check out whether the script autoNumberic.js has been successfully loaded or not.

Comment: Also found here: https://plugins.jquery.com/autoNumeric/ from jQuery page

Comment: It is successfully loaded.  I still get the error?  Any idea why, this also happens with jquery.timepicker.  Both scripts are loaded but same `is not a function` error.

Comment: Check that the script contains that function and check the casing of the function call.

Answer (score 5):

As of January 2018 the AutoNumeric plugin needs a different initialisation:

```
$(function() {
    new AutoNumeric('your-selector', yourOptions);
});
```

Also the option names have changed. See [github](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric).

Comment: your answer should be marked as answered, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You only have `jQuery` and `jQuery-ui` loaded.  I don't think `autoNumeric` is part of either of those packages.

You should try downloading from [HERE](https://plugins.jquery.com/autoNumeric/) or [HERE](http://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric) and see if it loads then.

Comment: I've downloaded autoNumeric and included the js file in my folder.

Comment: nope,  this is what is puzzling me.  Any idea why, conflict with other plugin?

Comment: @user892134 Could you update your question with all of the scripts you're using?

Comment: i've added the other scripts.

Comment: @user892134, When you go to the site you've included (`http://www.example.co.uk/assets/js/autoNumeric.js`) this shows an error that says "NOTICE! You've requested a file that is not available for remote inclusion." Is this your site? do you have access/privileges to use this file? or is that just me seeing this error?  It should be showing the actual JS code

Comment: I just put `example.co.uk` because i don't want my web address on stackoverflow.  The script is there.

Comment: @user892134, Doh - my stupidity. Are you able to check inspect your page, traverse the page until you find the script you've included and open the link in a new tab?  This will show the code perfectly.  Maybe there's an extra slash or something in the link?  Also, have you tried including the script in the head, instead of in the input?

Comment: @user892134, Also, have you tried using a relative path instead of an absolute path?

Comment: Ok, i can transverse the page and open the link in a new tab.  Also i put the scrip in the head and still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved,

Instead of wrapping in tags like this

```
$(function() {
    $(".employee_annual_salary").autoNumeric('init');
});
```

I wrapped in tags like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".employee_annual_salary").autoNumeric('init');
});
```

Now the function is working.

Comment: In order to avoid writing jQuery everytime and keep consistent with the beloved $ symbol, you can encapsulate the code inside an iife, like this:

(function($) {

  $(function() {
    $('body').append('Yey no more $ troubles here');
  });

})(jQuery);